# Unit testing support for Corda.v2 Contract?

Tags: java, unit-testing, corda

I'm using Corda V2 (in Java) and have a Contract in desperate need of a unit test.  But quickly going down a rabbit hole of trying to reverse engineer the creation of a `net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction`.  Is there any framework support for testing `MyContract` method `verify()`?

```
public class MyContract implements Contract {
// This is used to identify our contract when building a transaction.
public static final String MY_CONTRACT_ID = "com.exchange.data.address.MyContract";

// Our Create command.
public static class Create implements CommandData {
}

@Override
public void verify(LedgerTransaction tx) {
    final CommandWithParties<MyContract.Create> command = requireSingleCommand(tx.getCommands(), MyContract.Create.class);

    requireThat(check -> {
        // Constraints on the shape of the transaction.
        check.using("No inputs should be consumed when exchanging data.", tx.getInputs().isEmpty());
        check.using("There should be one output state of type MyState.", tx.getOutputs().size() == 1);

        final MyState out = tx.outputsOfType(MyState.class).get(0);
        final Party sender = out.getSender();
        final Party receiver = out.getReceiver();
        check.using("The sender and the receiver cannot be the same entity.", !sender.getName().equals(receiver.getName()));

        // Constraints on the signers.
        final List<PublicKey> signers = command.getSigners();
        check.using("There must be two signers.", signers.size() == 2);
        check.using("The sender and receiver must be signers.", signers.containsAll(
                ImmutableList.of(sender.getOwningKey(), receiver.getOwningKey())));

        return null;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Corda's contract testing framework.

The API docs are here: https://docs.corda.net/api-testing.html#contract-testing (note that these are for V3. These docs did not exist for V2).

You can see some example usages here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V2/java-source/src/test/java/com/example/contract/IOUContractTests.java.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that earlier, good examples and was able to adapt to my logic

Comment: We didn't document it until V3, because the test API wasn't stabilised.